# Hide a div with clicking the page background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

On my site, i have an autocomplete search. If i start typing what i am searching for, it puts out the records with ajax into the #country_list_id div.

Now, if i want to hide this div with the results, i can do it, by deleteing the keyword from the text input.

How can i hide it, by clicking the page background or an another element on the site?

```
<div class="input-group stylish-input-group bc-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control header_search_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Termékek keresése..." name="country_id" id="country_id" onkeyup="autocomplet();" >
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <button type="submit" class="header_search_button"><i class="fa fa-search header_search_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bc-menu list-group" id="country_list_id"></div>




function autocomplet()
{
    var min_length = 2;
    var keyword = $.trim($('#country_id').val());
    if (keyword.length >= min_length)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'files/search.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#country_list_id').show();
                $('#country_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#country_list_id').hide();
    }
}
function set_item(item)
{
    $('#country_id').val(item);
    $('#country_list_id').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

Use `document` click

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    $('#country_list_id').hide();
});
```

and add `script` file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, its okey!

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation - add a listener to `document.body`, and check to see if the clicked target is inside `#country_list_id`. If not, hide `#country_list_id`:

```js
$(document).on('click', (e) => {
  const { target } = e;
  if (!target.closest('#country_list_id')) $('#country_list_id').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>outer content 1 (click will hide)</div>
<div>outer content 2 (click will hide)
  <div class="bc-menu list-group" id="country_list_id">list content (click will not hide)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add an event listener to the body, and check if the `event.target` is equal to your search element, if it is not then hide it.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  //your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways: You could toggle your css for the div (onclick) and add/remove a class with `display:none;` , e.g. `.hidden { display: none; }`
I would advise this method if you want to hide the div completely.

if you want some of the div to remain visible, but it's taking up too much space, you could use a 'read more' / enlarge/shrink effect as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/nf39rjje/) (I've posted the code elsewhere in another answer before so i won't post it again!)

Best of luck

Comment: here's an example of hiding a div with display:none; http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/652fozjs/  (it's a radio button fiddle, but the same principle applies)